# How to exclude word from matching that is optional using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to match the following:

```
top of pole
top of existing pole
existing top of pole
```

but not

```
proposed top of pole
```

I tried to use `((!=proposed)\s)*top\sof\s(existing\s)?pole` with look back, but it doesn't quite work, still matching `proposed` top of pole.

How to exclude certain word when it is optional?

Comment: If it's excluded, how is it optional?

Comment: @Acccumulation there doesn't have to be any word before `top`. If there is, the word can't be `proposed`

Comment: What about `top of proposed pole`?

Comment: That's a rather weird way of phrasing it. You seem to be saying "There can be something before 'top', but it can't be 'proposed'", when you can just say "I don't want 'proposed' before 'top'"> Are you okay with "proposed" after "top"?

Comment: `(!=` is no *lookbehind*, the syntax is eg [`(?<!proposed\s)`...](https://regex101.com/r/eHkMqs/1)

Comment: @Nick `top of proposed pole` is not accepted which is already handled here.

Comment: You probably just want `\s*(?!proposed\s)top\sof\s(existing\s)?pole`

Comment: @bobblebubble this works! can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude a certain word like this:

```
(\w+\s(?<!proposed\s))?top\sof\s(existing\s)?hole
```

There are a couple of things going on in this solution:

- `\w+\s` matches a word and 1 whitespace character,
- The negative lookbehind `(?<!proposed\s)` gurantees that, once the regex is at this position after the word and space, looking backwards we do not match "proposed ".
- The `(...)?` makes the (word, space, and no "proposed ") match optional.

For a more detailed walkthrough: https://regex101.com/r/LLs2zA/1